# Use first $(this) in second forEach()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've been looking on the web about this issue i'm facing..

I can't find the way to use, in my second nested loop, my first $(this).
I would like something like Php do with aliases ?

Does someone knows if it's possible ?

You can see my code below to represent the problem.

```
$(".btn-labeled").click(function()
{
  var uid = $(this).parent().prev("td").html();
  $.get( "?what="+uid, function( data ) {
  var parsedJson =  JSON.parse(data);

  $(".rule").each(function()
  {
    var serviceAccount = $(this).children("td").html();
    parsedJson.forEach(function(iteration)
    {
      if(iteration["service_account"] != serviceAccount)
      {
        //I want this to be attached to first loop :p
        $(this).children("td").next("td").children("div").children("input").removeAttr("checked");
      }
    });

  });


    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable `element` reference that in the inner loop:

```
$(".btn-labeled").click(function()
{
  var uid = $(this).parent().prev("td").html();
  $.get( "?what="+uid, function( data ) {
  var parsedJson =  JSON.parse(data);

  $(".rule").each(function()
  {
   var element = $(this);//here
    var serviceAccount = $(this).children("td").html();
    parsedJson.forEach(function(iteration)
    {
      if(iteration["service_account"] != serviceAccount)
      {
       element.children("td").next("td").children("div").children("input").removeAttr("checked");
      }
    });

  });


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set outer context object as variable and then use it inside:

```
 $(".rule").each(function(){
var obj= $(this);
var serviceAccount = $(this).children("td").html();
parsedJson.forEach(function(iteration)
{
  if(iteration["service_account"] != serviceAccount)
  {
    //I want this to be attached to first loop :p
    obj.children("td").next("td").children("div").children("input").removeAttr("checked");
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the `$(this)` to a variable and then use that variable there after.

Like `var $this = $(this);`

```
$(".btn-labeled").click(function()
{
  var uid = $(this).parent().prev("td").html();     

  $.get( "?what="+uid, function( data ) {
  var parsedJson =  JSON.parse(data);

  $(".rule").each(function()
  {

    var $this = $(this); // assign $(this) to a new variable

    var serviceAccount = $(this).children("td").html();
    parsedJson.forEach(function(iteration)
    {
      if(iteration["service_account"] != serviceAccount)
      {
        //Use that variable
        $this.children("td").next("td").children("div").children("input").removeAttr("checked");
      }
    });

  });


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `this` in Javascript is dynamic scope. It depends on how the function is called and not how the author has written his code (like in lexical scope)

So your code should be like this

```
$(".btn-labeled").click(function()
{
  var uid = $(this).parent().prev("td").html();
  $.get( "?what="+uid, function( data ) {
  var parsedJson =  JSON.parse(data);
  // save reference to this also it is good idea to prefix variables containing jQuery objects with a $
  var $outer_this = $(this) 
  $(".rule").each(function()
  {
    var serviceAccount = $outer_this.children("td").html();
    parsedJson.forEach(function(iteration)
    {
      if(iteration["service_account"] != serviceAccount)
      {
        //I want this to be attached to first loop :p
        $outer_this.children("td").next("td").children("div").children("input").removeAttr("checked");
      }
    });

  });


    });
});
```

The inner functions are able to access the outer variables because the inner functions have closure over the variables of outer function.